# How can I reuse the code of a generic interface in a extension method?

Tags: c#

XYZ is a class for a 3D point;
Coordinate is the information about the position of the point. (this could be the polar/cartesian coordinate for instance)

I have this interface:

```
interface ICreateOrderOnASpace<Coordinate,T>{
    Coordinate getPosition(XYZ p);
    int ComparaisonPosition(Coordinate c1, Coordinate c2);
     

}
```

And I would like to create an extension method that orders a list of elements thanks to a function that give a point 3d from the element

```
class CreateOrderOnASpaceExtensions<Coordinate,T>{
    IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderElements(this ICreateOrderOnASpace<Coordinate,T> myInterface, IEnumerable<T> elements,Func<T,XYZ> f){
        elements.OrderBy(
                x => myInterface.getPosition(f(x)),
                Comparer<Coordinate>.Create(myInterface.ComparaisonPosition)
                )
    }
}
```

> Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

What is the best way to do that if I can't use generic?

Comment: If only a few methods of your class need to be generic - or as in your case you have only one - you may chose to make the class non-generic. In fact there´s no real reason to make the class itself generic in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make the class non-generic and static, and extension method generic instead:

```cs
static class CreateOrderOnASpaceExtensions
{
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderElements<Coordinate,T>(
        this ICreateOrderOnASpace<Coordinate,T> myInterface,
        IEnumerable<T> elements,Func<T,XYZ> f)
        => elements.OrderBy(
            x => myInterface.getPosition(f(x)),
                Comparer<Coordinate>.Create(myInterface.ComparaisonPosition)
        );
}
```